# Powers of Sugreva, Jambwant, Nal, Neel and Angad

Tags: ramayana

In Ramayana, we hear of many Vanaras (Monkeys) having various powers like Nal-Neel have the power of throwing anything in water and they will float, Angad having power of increasing his tail size and even making it to use like a chair or putting his leg  on ground such that no one could pull it up.

Similarly Jambwant is also said to be able to fly to distant places in his young age and Lord Hanuman we all know. So, I just wanted to know what all other powers did Angad, Nal, Neel, Jambwant and Sugreeva actually had and also how did they get those powers.